# Validity of Laplace's equation in ohmic conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

In Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics* chapter 7, he states Ohm's law:

$$\vec{J}=\sigma \vec {E}$$

He also states that if

$$\frac{\partial {\rho}}{\partial {t}}=0$$

then $$\frac {1} {\sigma} \vec {\nabla} \cdot \vec {J} = \vec {\nabla} \cdot \vec {E} = 0$$

However, if we assume that

$$\vec {J} = \rho v \hat {z}$$

where $v$ and $\rho$ is a constant $\rho_{0}$ when $x^2+y^2 \le r$ and $0$ elsewhere; shouldn't

$$\vec {\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \frac {\rho} {\epsilon_{0}}$$

when $x^2+y^2 \le r$.

This creates a contradiction. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\rho$ in Gauss's law $\nabla\cdot E=\frac\rho{\epsilon_0}$ is the *net* charge density $\rho_\text{net}$. The $\rho$ in your proposed current should be *the density of moving charge* $\rho_\text{moving}.$ There is no reason for these two densities to be the same, and you've proven that in fact they *must not* be the same. In a real wire, the electrons that move to carry the current are counterbalanced by an equal density of ions that do not participate in the current.
\begin{align}
\rho_\text{net}=\rho_\text{ions}+\rho_\text{moving}=0&\implies\nabla\cdot\vec E=\frac{\rho_\text{net}}{\epsilon_0}=0,\\
\vec J=\rho_\text{moving}v\hat z&\implies\nabla\cdot\vec J=0=\sigma\nabla\cdot
\vec E.\end{align}
You've shown that if you had a "wire" composed of just a beam of electrons with no ions to hold them, the "wire" would blow itself apart.